# Error when i Bind Or Connect With UDP Protocol (ZeroMQException(156384764): The protocol is not compatible with the socket type)

Tags: flutter, dart, udp, zeromq

i use SocketType.sub and SocketType.pub to connect and bind from udp address
i watched documentation of zmq and i must use socket type as like Radio and Dish but i can't find it in dartzmq

my simple code like this :

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dartzmq/dartzmq.dart';

void dishRadioDart() async {
  String udpAddress = "udp://127.0.0.1:5566";
  final context = ZContext();
  final dishSocket = context.createSocket(SocketType.pub);
  final radioSocket = context.createSocket(SocketType.sub);

  try {
    dishSocket.bind(udpAddress);
    print("dish socket binded to address : ${udpAddress}");
    radioSocket.connect(udpAddress);
    print("radio socket connect to address : ${udpAddress}");
    radioSocket.setOption(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "");

    radioSocket.payloads.listen((event) {
      print("received message");
      print("received message is : ${event}");
    });
    while (true) {
      print("send message ");
      dishSocket.sendString("abdullah message ");
      sleep(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("error e : ${e}");
  }
}
```

i asked that in github too , any one can see that from this link : https://github.com/enwi/dartzmq/issues/31

in the end i'm trying to use udp protocol with zeromq in my flutter application to send and receive some control items between python application and flutter application .
any one can help me here .

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that, whilst you've called the sockets `dish` and `radio`, you are in fact creating them as `pub` and `sub` which do not work over a UDP connection. Take a look at the ZMQ C API reference [here](https://libzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/zmq_udp.html).

Also, I'm slightly wary of how you're receiving messages over such a transport. It looks like you've set up a call back on the receive event. That will need to be run asynchronously, otherwise the UDP packet will vanish before anything happens. I don't know how ZMQ is implemented in Python. If it's a binding of the standard C library then it's OK because that'll have a separate management thread for the socket anyway (and that will be running asynchronously to the rest of your code). Otherwise, if it's a python thread subject to the GIL (depending on the version of Python being used) then whilst it might look asynchronous in the source code it may not actually be running asynchronously. This wouldn't matter for any other transport (like tcp, ipc), but might for udp. Best thing is to swap to actual dish and radio sockets, try it, see what happens!